# SyncHttpClient onFailure was not overriden

Tags: java, android

I am getting this message whenever i try to upload an image to my server.

```
onFailure(int, Header[], Throwable, JSONObject) was not overriden, but callback was received

java.net.SocketTimeoutException

at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:491)

at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:46) ...
```

As you can see i did override onFailure(int, Header[], Throwable,JSONObject) method but still get the error.

```
 SyncHttpClient client = new SyncHttpClient();
    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
    params.put("imagedata", encodedString);

 client.post(Config.UPDATETOSERVER, params, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response)                                                             {
            super.onSuccess(statusCode, headers, response);
                 Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: ");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, Throwable throwable, JSONObject errorResponse) {
            super.onFailure(statusCode, headers, throwable, errorResponse);
            Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: ");
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString, Throwable throwable) {
            super.onFailure(statusCode, headers, responseString, throwable);
             Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: ");
        }

    });
```

Can anyone help me please !

Comment: Finally i found what is the problem , After days of searching and after getting banned from posting questions ...
Just adding this line to build gradle file solve my problem 
         compile 'cz.msebera.android:httpclient:4.3.6'